# Is it possible to merge few rows into one in Hive?

Tags: hive

I have a table with like this:

```
Source  Target   Date
A             B             2018-01-14
B             C             2018-06-29
C             D             2019-03-05
```

My aim is to create path like this: ABCD
In Oracle I would use CONNECT BY function, but is it possible to do in in Hive?

Answer (score 0):

select col1,col2,date,concat(x,lead(y) over ()) from ( select *,concat(col1,col2,lead(col2) over ()) as x,lead(col2) over () as y from table ) x;